# How to use react refs for dynamically generated table rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 let tablebody = schedule.map((element, index) => {
  const columns = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= numTransactions; i++) {
    if (i == element.transaction) {
      schedule[index].ref = React.createRef();
      columns.push(
        <ArcherElement
          id={
            element.transaction +
            element.action +
            (element.dataitem ? element.dataitem : '')
          }
          ref={schedule[index].ref}
        >
          <td>
            {' '}
            {element.action + (element.dataitem ? element.dataitem : '')}
          </td>
        </ArcherElement>
      );
    } else {
      columns.push(<td></td>);
    }
  }
```

So I am creating a dynamic table and I want to be able to access each column of the table for further processing, in particular, the  ArcherElement in there and its properties? This code does not work as the ref object is null when I try to access it.
Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Is it really `null` or just not (behaving as) an ArcherElement? In case of the latter, you maybe forgot you have to access it as `schedule[index].ref.current`. Just an idea...

Comment: Does react refs work only for html elements and not components itself?